# How to set transparent background to grabcut output image with open cv?

Tags: android, opencv

[image]> Hi, I am using OpenCV android library grabcut() method to extract an image from background, but the problem is that the output bitmap contains background Same as original image and object become white .I need Object as its same as original image and background transparent

I am using this code

```
private static Bitmap makeBlackTransparent(Bitmap image) {
    // convert image to matrix
    Mat src = new Mat(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(image, src);

    // init new matrices
    Mat dst = new Mat(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Mat tmp = new Mat(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Mat alpha = new Mat(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);

    // convert image to grayscale
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // threshold the image to create alpha channel with complete transparency in black background region and zero transparency in foreground object region.
    Imgproc.threshold(tmp, alpha, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

    // split the original image into three single channel.
    List<Mat> rgb = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
    Core.split(src, rgb);

    // Create the final result by merging three single channel and alpha(BGRA order)
    List<Mat> rgba = new ArrayList<Mat>(4);
    rgba.add(rgb.get(0));
    rgba.add(rgb.get(1));
    rgba.add(rgb.get(2));
    rgba.add(alpha);
    Core.merge(rgba, dst);

    // convert matrix to output bitmap
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(dst, output);
    return output;
}
```

[image: This is my souce image]

Comment: Can you share the source image as well ?

Comment: @Zdar please check at top i have added source image

Comment: So you want that circular thing in foreground and the white portion as background, Also I don't see any grabCut related code in your snippet ?

Comment: yes , i want boy in image as it   is in source image and the background white, actually i am  using open cv sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

Firstly you need to segment out the white background, so adjust your thresh to be near 220 - 240 and also use `THRESH_BINARY_INV` instead of `THRESH_BINARY` :

```
Imgproc.threshold(tmp, alpha, 230, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

Secondly, you must pre-multiply the ARGB layers, as Android ImageView behaves weird without premultiplication, for that you need to use `cvtColor` with `COLOR_RGBA2mRGBA` flag:

```
// Create the final result by merging three single channel and alpha(BGRA order)
List<Mat> rgba = new ArrayList<Mat>(4);
rgba.add(rgb.get(0));
rgba.add(rgb.get(1));
rgba.add(rgb.get(2));
rgba.add(alpha);
Core.merge(rgba, dst);

Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2mRGBA);
```

Comment: thanx for the help but i am still in trouble , because using this code my round image become same as source one, and imageview background become black

Comment: Can you share the output using the above code? I guess you need to set the background color of your image View, otherwise default Android imageView treats alpha as black

Comment: HI. i m facing some issue in OpenCV not able to make background clear